# Stacking background images on top of each other CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following 1920x1080 image and I want to vertically stack this image so that when I scroll, it looks like one continuous path as the background of a website. I have tried different stuff but I cant seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with the following snippet:

```
body{
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJLIF.png) repeat-y center/contain;
}
```

```css
body{
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJLIF.png) repeat-y center/contain;
}
div{
 height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you :) So what if they were 2 different images, is this still possible? So for example if the start and end of another path is the same but the middle section is different

Comment: You should probably try out some things and when you're stuck with the progress of your code, reach out. It will most definitely benefit you in the long run ;)

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner...I am just trying to learn by doing. I keep getting syntax errors or the image does not fit the screen. I have tried a lot

Comment: You need to post your code of trials and possible errors. This way people can improve upon it.